# Build a go binary for both Linux and Mac

Tags: go

How can I `go build` a project in a way that it works for both Mac and Linux (x86 and x64)? Is that even possible?

I searched and found some stuff, but cannot make them work (or maybe I just didn't understood them).

Comment: You cannot build a single binary that runs on both Mac and Linux, if that is what you mean. They use different binary formats, Mach-O and ELF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To build binaries for different platforms, I use [GOX](https://github.com/mitchellh/gox)

> Gox is a simple, no-frills tool for Go cross compilation that behaves
>   a lot like standard go build. Gox will parallelize builds for multiple
>   platforms. Gox will also build the cross-compilation toolchain for
>   you.

You tell it which platforms you want to target, and one command will build a separate binary for each of them. One binary cannot target multiple systems though.

To build for OSX (64 bit) and Linux (32 and 64 bit), you could use:

```
gox -osarch="darwin/amd64 linux/386 linux/amd64"
```